# Wordpress Menu CSS Issues

Tags: wordpress, css

Hi so I am working on creating a **wordpress template** from an existing static website.

However I can't seem to get the CSS for the menu to work correctly.
I need a style that is applied to the menu to be applied to all of the li and not have to code each one individually.

The problem is I want to add a `background-color` to each item (making them look like buttons). If you look at the site again, it puts a huge box rather than putting a small `background-color` to each item. I hope that makes sense.

You can see the site here: http://lawrences.work/

Comment: You need a CSS selector? What is *going wrong?* because `#menu-menu li { ...css... }` just works

Answer (score 1):

First, remove your width:149px; on #menu-menu.

Second, on #menu-menu li, remove all margins, and try apply this code

```
# menu-menu li {
background-color: #FFC0CB;
display: inline;
padding: 10px 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so I've checked it out and it appears to be that the `div#logo` is causing your menu to be vertically stretched.

I'm not entirely sure as to why since I didn't scan all the CSS or couldn't find anything related to it directly.

Either way I do have an explanation for what actually happened anyways.
So this `div.menu-menu-container` in your HTML is lexically positioned just below the `div#logo` - if you *inspect element* on them you should see highlighting overlap when hovering between the two.

An element that is `float: left` basically has no height. It is *sort-of* removed from the document flow unless the div below it has `clear: both` or the parent has `overflow: hidden` - both which have their own nasty side-effects.

Anyway, this `div#logo` caused your `div.menu-menu-container` to stretch vertically because the `div#logo` was *floated* and your `div.menu-menu-container` wasn't causing it to be quirky.

To fix this I added one property to `div.menu-menu-container` which should not harm your layout in any way except for keeping these floated elements out of your way.

the property `clear: both` allows you to *clear* a float so that the document flow after it turns back to normal. This shrunk your menu down to the size it's supposed to be in the position it's supposed to be in.

### EDIT (18-11-2015)

I actually had a choice of using `clear: both` or `float: left` - both fix the issue since all floated elements do think about each other, just not about the non-floated elements as much.

`clear: both` however is the nicest solution in this case because it doesn't change the behaviour of that element specifically whereas floating it does.

Also, the snippet you're going to need for your code to work:

```
.menu-menu-container {
    clear: both; // or float: left; for that matter
}
```

For more reading on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/) / [css-tricks](https://css-tricks.com)

- [float](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float)
- [clear](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clear)
- [css-tricks on float](https://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/)

Hope this helps you understand your issue, if you need more information I'll see it in the comments!

Good luck